# Probability of the sum of 2 dice being even or odd

Tags: probability

2 players are playing a game involving 2 dice. Player A wins if the sum is odd whereas Player B wins if the sum is even. Player A complains that the game is unfair due to the chance of rolling an odd number is 5/11 and even is 6/11. **Explore the validity of this statement and the fairness of the game.** I know the actual probability is 18/36 for both even and odd but i'm not sure how to put it into words

Comment: how is that so?

Comment: **Hint** What is the probability that the first of the two die rolls is even? The second? Using this, what is the probability that the sum of the two rolls is even?

Comment: the probability that the sum of the two rolls is even is 18/36 and odd is 18/36. The question is only asking about the probability of the sum of the two die.

Answer (score 6):

Let's throw the dice one by one.

The first die will show a face.

The second die has $3$ faces that make the sum even and $3$ faces that make the sum  odd.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: 5/11 and 6/11.

The possible sum of rolling two dice is 2,3,4.....,12.  Total 11 possibilities, 5 odds and 6 evens. 
Now, the probability of each sum value is not alike for all possibilities. 
For eg., 
sum 2 - (1,1) - prob: 1/36
Sum 3 - (1,2),(2,1) - prob: 2/36
.
.
Sum 10- (5,5),(4,6),(6,4) prob:3/36
Sum 12-(6,6) prob:1/36
Hence, had it been the sum probabilities are same then 5/11 and 6/11 are valid. But since the probabilities are different, actual probabilities of odds is 18/36 or 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

To answer A's critique consider the following:

The probability that two coins when tossed together turn up the same is ${1\over2}$, even though two of the three visible possibilities are "favorable".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: **Explore the validity of this statement and the fairness of the game** I need an answer for this

Comment: @BLAZE: My answer is neither a critique nor a request for clarification. It just describes the problem in a nutshell, and as such is  an invitation to resolve the problem on his/her own.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Okay, It just seemed more like a comment (your initial version). Sorry, I thought I was just following the guidelines under the low-quality posts review, which is what someone flagged it as. I guess the lesson is never try to close a answer made by someone with a very high rep since it __always__ get disputed.